# Convert to polar $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to transform

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$$

to polar form?

Comment: I think this double integral diverges

Comment: Any way, it'll be $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $0<r<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$- and $y$-limits both being $(0, +\infty)$ means that your area of integration is the entire first quadrant.  How do you describe the entire first quadrant in polar coordinates?

Remember that $r$ describes your distance from the pole (the origin) and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ describes the angle.  Can you see how to use these two things together to describe the entire first quadrant?

First think about the angles in $[0,2\pi]$ that bound the first quadrant.  Then think about what the distance from the pole needs to go from and to in order to cover the entire thing.

Comment: It's from 0 to infinity and the question asked me to put it in polar form and solve it. I'm not sure how I would find the angle and r that describes the first quadrant.

Comment: Sorry about that!  Will update my post.

Comment: ok so since its the first quadrant i would set the integration limits from 0 to pi/2 and 0 to inf and get the limit as r approaches infinity right

Comment: @ShadyAF yep, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating over the first quadrant, so $0<r<\infty$ and $0<\theta<{\pi \over 2}$

You also have to swap the differentials: $dxdy=dA=rdrd\theta$

Then just use the fact than $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and rewrite the integral as $$\int_0^{\pi \over 2}\int_0^\infty{r \over {\sqrt{1+r^2}}}drd\theta$$ The integral diverges.